# LDAP application account authentication using Java

Tags: java, ldap

Would like to know if we can **authenticate an applicationName & password against LDAP**. In our LDAP system, I can see 'Applications' branch apart from 'Groups', 'People' etc..Need to do this check to do some action.

I'm looking for documentation or sample code to do it in Java.

Thank you,

Comment: Is it really that weired/specific feature? Please throw some light on it. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JNDI. See the Oracle JNDI tutorial. It is very extensive and it has a large section on LDAP.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yeah, it's very extensive. Do you think this section is useful? I need to validate application accounts. Thanks. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html